# how to clean imports Nodejs Mongodb socket io

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, socket.io

I am Using MongoDB socket.io with nodeJs. Is there any way to clean up my imports

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const { createServer } = require("http");
const httpServer = createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
var config = require("./config");
const url = config.mongoUrl;
```

Comment: What do mean **`clean`** ? You really can't import packages in one variable.

Comment: Was not sure if there was a way that I could redo my imports so that my code does not look so cluttered just with imports

Answer (score 0):

Just use typescript, and then import with es6 syntax:

```js
// tsconfig.json (at the root of your repository)
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "lib": ["es6"],
      "allowJs": true,
      "outDir": "build",
      "rootDir": "src",
      "strict": false,
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "baseUrl": "./",
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "build"]
  }
  
// imports src/index.ts
import express from "express";
import { createServer } from "http";
import Mongoose from "mongoose";
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import { mongoUrl as url } from "./config"

export const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);
```

If you prefer to keep the `require` syntax, then you could shorten your `app()` declaration:

```js
const app = require('express')();
```